# Авторизация на сайтах (POST запросы c#)

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, post

В общем походу написания проекта возникла потребность совершать авторизацию на нескольких сайтах. Единого подхода тут не будет(или я его попросту не вижу). В идеале авторизацию через vk. Читал запросы браузера. Вроде написал запрос который должен работать, а он не хочет. Думаю тут дело в скриптах. Сайт как-то понимает, что запросы не из браузера. Тут нужен браузер в котором можно заполнять данные форм (и обязательно с поддержкой прокси раз уж на то пошло), в идеале конечно. Ну, или хотя бы способ выполнять скрипты в html. Посоветуйте какую-то либу, если такая есть вообще.

Так же не отказался бы от какой-либо литературы связанной с запросами, ибо сами запросы понимаю только в общих чертах, а откуда какие параметры берутся, могу только предполагать. Или если кто может подсказать софт упрощающий задачу (хром вроде как справляется, но.. вероятно уже придумали что-то лучше)

PS. Сейчас использую HttpClient, формирую HttpWebRequest и отправляю.

Comment: Запускайте Fiddler и смотрите, чем запрос из вашей программы отличается от запроса браузера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с VK есть специальные библиотеки. Откройте ["Менеджер пакетов"](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) и введите в поиск VK. Выбирайте из первых 5. Там же будут ссылки на офф сайты, откуда можно почитать документацию.

Если же вам надо работать не с ВК. То я бы посоветовал [xNet](https://habr.com/ru/post/146475/) как обертку над httpClient. Для начала с ней работать гораздо проще. Хотя и имеются некоторые ограничения и возможно, однажды, в далеком будущем, вам придется ковырять исходник, что бы, например, включить TLS1.2.

Вам нужно почитать про HTTP-протокол, желательно в публицистической форме для начала. Он простой как блокнот.